# In a rails 3.2 app, how can I populate an array in a controller with a collection defined in a model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

In a view have a collection for a pull down menu (using the simple form gem):

```
<%= f.input :item, :collection => MyModel::CATEGORY %>
```

The collection is populated in my model:

```
CATEGORY = [["Category", 5], ["Another", 4], ["This", 3], ["That", 2], ["Foo", 1]]
```

Rather than recreating it, I'd like to use it also in my controller:

```
@category = []
@category << ProductDevelopment::CATEGORY
```

What I would really like is an array populated like this:

```
@category[1] = "Foo"
@category[2] = "That"
@category[3] = "This"
@category[4] = "Another"
@category[5] = "Category"
```

Searched but can't seem to locate the proper syntax to do this. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@category = MyModel::CATEGORY.map{ |arr| arr[0] }
```

**Not tested

Comment: Beware... This will NOT output the result you expect:  `["Category", "Another", "This", "That", "Foo"] !=  ["Foo", "That", "This", "Another", "Category"]` Also, this is highly dependent on the order of items in the array you provide.

Comment: See a more comprehensive approach below.

Answer (score 2):

```
@category = MyModel::CATEGORY.sort{|x,y| x[1] <=> y[1]}.map{|c| c[0]}
```

The `sort` part simply sorts your categories based on the number associated to them, then the `map` creates a new array only containing the category names.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you do not do this.
Use a enumeration gem like those: https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/categories/Active_Record_Enumerations
IMO is more testable, reusable and maintainable.

Answer (score 1):

Given `CATEGORIES = [ ['a', 1], ['b', 2], ... ]` with items in *any* order where the elements represent categories with elements `[category, index]`, you have two choices of data structure from which to select.

1. An `Array` where you can look up categories by index

   Be careful with this choice. As you'll necessarily have a `0` index for which you'll need to account out of the box.

   ```
   # Mix things up for kicks
   categories = CATEGORIES.shuffle

   categories.inject([]){|memo,cat|  memo[cat[1]] = cat[0]; memo }
   # => [nil, 'a', 'b']
   ```

   You'll also need to worry about `nil` entries if you ever choose to remove a category. Say you delete `['d', 4]`. You'd now see the following:

   ```
   # => [nil, 'a', 'b', 'c', nil, 'e', ...]
   ```
2. A `Hash` where you can look up the categories by key

   This will avoid the whole issue with `nil` values will occur when using arrays:

   ```
   # Mix things up for kicks
   categories = CATEGORIES.shuffle
   categories.inject({}){ |memo,cat| memo.merge!({cat[1]=>cat[0]}) }
   # => {2=>'a', 1=>'b'}
   ```

I'd personally recommend the `Hash`, and as far as I know, hashes play well with collections in most Rails form builders.